# How to pass result from MySQLi Query from one PHP page to another?

Tags: php, mysql

I have `Page1.php` containing various functions. A variable `$response` is there containing result from MySQLi query.
I have another page `Page2.php` which can display results from SQL query in very formatted way.
How can I pass, `$response` from `Page1.php` to `Page2.php`?

I tried following.

**In page 1:**

```
session_start();  
$_SESSION['message'] = $response;  
header("Location:Page2.php");  
die();
```

**In page 2:**

```
 session_start();  
    $response = $_SESSION['message'];
```

But, it isn't working. :(
Any other method to pass this result from one page to another is also welcome..!

Comment: why not include page 1 in page 2? http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php than you can access it's variables direct

Comment: Do you get anything in page 2 when you do `print_r($_SESSION);`

Comment: In normal case this will work, have you checked the output (echo $response; )?

Comment: What will you get in page1 when you do `var_dump($response);` ?

Comment: AG21 Yes, print_r($_SESSION) shows me: _Array([message] => mysqli_result Object )_

But, when I try to use that object like: `$response->data_seek(0);`  
It says: **Warning:** mysqli_result::data_seek(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the clean method as below in `Page1.php`:

```
/* seek to row no. 1 */
$response->data_seek(0);

/* fetch row */
$data = $response->fetch_row();

$_SESSION['message'] = $data;

session_write_close();

header("Location:Page2.php");

die();
```

**Page2.php**

```
session_start(); 

$response = $_SESSION['message'];
```

Hope this helps.